# Is Regex faster than array comparison in this case?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, performance, parsing

Say I have an incoming string that I want scan to see if it contains any of the words I have chosen to be "bad." :)

Is it faster to split the string into an array, as well as keep the bad words in an array, and then iterate through each bad word as well as each incoming word and see if there's a match, kind of like:

```
badwords.each do |badword|
 incoming.each do |word|
  trigger = true if badword == word
 end
end
```

OR is it faster to do this:

```
incoming.each do |word|
 trigger = true if badwords.include? word
end
```

OR is it faster to leave the string as it is and run a .match() with a regex that looks something like:

```
/\bbadword1\b|\bbadword2\b|\bbadword3\b/
```

Or is the performance difference almost completely negligible? Been wondering this for a while.

Comment: Stop wondering, start measuring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're giving the regex an advantage by not stopping your loop when it finds a match. Try:

```
incoming.find{|word| badwords.include? word}
```

My money is still on the regex though which should be simplified to:

```
/\b(badword1|badword2|badword3)\b/
```

or to make it a fair fight:

```
/\a(badword1|badword2|badword3)\z/
```

Comment: You can get another slight performance increase by using a non-capturing group.

Comment: Fantastic. Can you tell me why .find isn't listed as a method in ruby docs Array#find ?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the Enumerable module which Array includes.

Answer (score 3):

Once it is compiled, the Regex is the fastest in real live (i.e. really long incoming string, many similar bad words, etc.) since it can run on `incoming` [in situ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and will handle overlapping parts of your "bad words" really well.

Answer (score 2):

The answer probably depends on the number of bad words to check: if there is only one bad word it probably doesn't make a huge difference, if there are 50 then checking an array would probably get slow. On the other hand, with tens or hundreds of thousands of words the regexp probably won't be too fast either

If you need to handle large numbers of bad words, you might want to consider splitting into individual words and then using a bloomfilter to test whether the word is likely to be bad or not.

Answer (score 2):

This does not excatly answer your question but this will definitely help solve it.

Take some examples what your are tring to acheive and put them to bench marks.

you can find how to do benchmarking in ruby [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/f/benchmark.htm)

Just put the varoius forms between report block and get the benchmarks and decide yourself what suits you the best.

http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/f/benchmark.htm

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

For better solutions use the real data to test.

Benchmarks are always better than discussions :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scan a string for occurrences of words, use [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to find them.

Use [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to build a pattern that will find the strings in your black-list. You will want to wrap the result with `\b` to force matching word-boundaries, and use a case-insensitive search.

To give you an idea of how `Regexp.union` can help:

```
words = %w[foo bar]

Regexp.union(words)
=> /foo|bar/

'Daniel Foo killed him a bar'.scan(/\b#{Regexp.union(words)}\b/i)
=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

You could also build the pattern using `Regexp.new` or `/.../` if you want a bit more control:

```
Regexp.new('\b(?:' + words.join('|') + ')\b', Regexp::IGNORECASE)
=> /\b(?:foo|bar)\b/i

/\b(?:#{words.join('|')})\b/i
=> /\b(?:foo|bar)\b/i

'Daniel Foo killed him a bar'.scan(/\b(?:#{words.join('|')})\b/i)
=> ["Foo", "bar"]
```

As a word of advice, black-listing words you find offensive is easily tricked by a user, and often gives results that are wrong because many "offensive" words are only offensive in a certain context. A user can deliberately misspell them or use "l33t" speak and have an almost inexhaustible supply of alternate spellings that will make you constantly update your list. It's a source of enjoyment to some people to fool a system.

I was once given a similar task and wrote a translator to supply alternate spellings for "offensive" words. I started with a list of words and terms I'd gleaned from the Internet and started my code running. After several million alternates were added to the database I pulled the plug and showed management it was a fools-errand because it was trivial to fool it.

Comment: Good tip. In my case, I'm not filtering the words out but simply scanning to see if there's any - in that case, I'll need to serve different results if the query contains naughty words.